# Inheritance and private members

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  

class Base {  

private:  
    int b;  
public:  
    Base(int bvalue=0) {  
        b = bvalue;  
        cout << "B's ctor" << endl;  
    }  
    ~Base() { }  
};  

class Derv : public Base {  
public:  
   int d;  
   Derv(int bval, int dval) : Base(bval),d(dval) {  
       cout << "D's ctor" << endl;  
   }  
   Derv(int dval) : d(dval) {  
       cout << "D's ctor " << endl;  
  }  
};  

int main(){  
    Derv D1(4,5);  
    Derv D2(100);  
    return 0;  
}
```

The above program compiles fine and I see the output as

```
B's ctor  
D's ctor  
B's ctor  
D's ctor
```

Since private members of Base class are not inherited, what is the memory location the Base constructor is creating the private member in?

**NB:** This question contains a misconception which is fully addressed in the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Private members *are* inherited; they are just not *visible* from the member functions in the subclass. So in an instance of `Derv`, `b` and `d` will likely be adjacent to each other in memory (although the compiler may choose to place the variables differently). Member functions in `Derv` cannot see `b`, but if you call a function that is inherited from `Base`, that function will be able to see `b`.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies my doubt. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1: But it's not guaranteed that `b` and `d` will be **adjacent**

Comment: @6502: True; I refined my answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to ask, but whenever a derived class's constructor is called it calls its parent class's constructor first. Note that a *private* variable is only private to access from methods outside of a class (and its friends). Regardless of how the `Base` class's constructor was called, it will have access to its own private member variable *b*. In other words, `Derv` cannot access *b* directly, but it *can* call the `Base` constructor to modify *b* for it.

Furthermore, as Tomalak points out, every `Derived` object contains *a fully-constructed `Base` object, private members and all*. If `Base` was derived from another class—`CommonBase`, let's say—every `Derived` object would also contain a fully-constructed `CommonBase` object, as well.

In the interests of being thorough, note that unless you explicitly specify otherwise, derived classes will also implicitly call the *default constructor* of their parent class.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I know Derived class constroctor first calls its Base class constructor. But here since Base class constructor is initializing private member.. here does this private member reside. It is anyway not inherited.

Comment: @irappa: Yes it is. Part of the `Derived` object is a fully-constructed `Base` object, private members and all.