# Size of Derived class[2]

Tags: c++, oop

Why is the size of Derived class 80 in the following code?
According to me, the private data member will not be inherited and the `sizeof(Derived)` should print 40

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Base{
 int a[10];
    public:
    int b[10];
};
class Derived:public Base{

};
int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(Derived)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Good Question dear :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The size of base class object and derived class object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007797/the-size-of-base-class-object-and-derived-class-object-in-c)

Comment: Perfect duplicate of [Inheritance and private members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169152/inheritance-and-private-members)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the private data member is not accessible to the derived class does not mean that you are able to omit it. Consider:

```
class Base{
    int a[10];
 public:
    int b[10];
    int getFirstA() { return a[0]; }
};

class Derived:public Base{
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    int a = d.getFirstA();
}
```

The implementation of `Base` still relies on all private members being present. As the implementation of `Base` makes up the implementation of `Derived` it is not sensible to eliminate the private member here, even if it's not directly accessible to `Derived` and its clients.

Answer (score 3):

Private members are inherited, just not visible. You use private members to hide the implementation details, but the state has to be stored somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

> the private data member will not be inherited

Wrong!

Private data members are inherited, even though they are not visible.

> Why is the size of Derived class 80 in the following code?

As explained above, both arrays are inherited, thus affect the size of the class (in your system the size of an `int` seems to be 4, thus 10 * 4 + 10 * 4 = 80).

Answer (score 0):

We can not access private members but they are inherited. that is the reason  why the size is 80

So that size is `40+40=80`

Answer (score 0):

The private members just can not be accessed, but It will be inherited. Becase it contains 20 integers, so the size is 20 * 4 = 80.